# Is the initial value of the portfolio replicating a forward zero?

Tags: derivatives, risk-neutral-measure, asset-pricing, no-arbitrage-theory, synthetic

This is from the book Financial Calculus: An Introduction to Derivative Pricing by Martin Baxter.

By choosing appropriate weights in a portfolio of a stock and cash bond you can replicate the payoff of a forward.

Notation: we are now in State 1, with stock price $S_1$. In the future we will be in State 2 (with stock price $S_2$) with r.n. prob $1-q$, or in State 3 (stock price $S_3$) with r.n. probability $q$. The variable $f$ represents the payoff of the forward ($f_n=S_n-K$).

The value of the portfolio is
$$V=s_{1}\frac{f(3)-f(2)}{s_{3}-s_{2}}+e^{-r\delta t}\left(f(3)-\frac{\left(f(3)-f(2)\right)s_{3}}{s_{3}-s_{2}}\right) $$

This all makes sense to me and I understand how under a risk-neutral measure.

$$V = e^{-r \delta t}\left(\left(1-q\right)f(2)+qf(3)\right)$$

In one the exercises, the author asks for us to prove that using $V$, the strike price is $$S_1e^{r \delta t}$$.

I substitute $f(2)=s_{2}-k$ and $f(3)=s_{3}-k$ but I don’t end up with the desired answer. However I’m able to get $K= S_1e^{r \delta t}$ if I let $V=0$.

Is is it correct to let $V=0$? Or have I missed anything here? On one hand I know that initial value of the forward is 0 but I can’t get my head around how the initial value of the portfolio we have set up is also 0.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, the forward has initial value 0 and so the replicating portfolio must have this value also.

Comment: Hi, could you please explain what your variables represent? That would help us help you :)

Comment: Hi, so $s_{1}$ is the current stock price and $s_{2}$ and $S_{3}$ are it’s possible future values. As such $f(2)= s_{2}
-K$ and $f(3)= s_{3}-K $. In the second equation $q$ is the risk-neutral probability. Thanks!